# Background image to the row of Table with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply background image to table row, but it repeats the image in cells.

```
#tableid tr:hover{
background: url("images/tablerow.png");
height:45px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="table" id="tableid">
<tr>
<td>first cell</td>
<td>second cell</td>
<td>third cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you post your html as well and create a jsfiddle?

Comment: it works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/5es5k5qe/2/, just use background-image

Comment: in jsfiddle.net/5es5k5qe/2, it repeats the background image in cells.

Comment: No it's not, it's just repeating the background image throughout the row. Here I removed the background-repeat https://jsfiddle.net/5es5k5qe/4/